# Slidesjs autoHeight issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I use Slidesjs http://slidesjs.com/ and the problem is with autoHeight. Exactly in Chrome the height of slides is 0px but after clicking next slide the height become as it should be. Does any know how to fix that? And here is the link http://demo.themeuniverse.net/cottoncandy/

```
if (option.autoHeight) {
                control.children().css({
                    height: 'auto'
                });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite hard to tell with your example, much easier if you could reproduce the issue and put it on http://jsfiddle.net . Anyway I copy and pasted your html from source and managed to get it working on this fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/vrrnz/6/

I would also suggest giving your container a set width and height (seeing as it's probably not likely to be changing).

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer, but I don't understand what exactly you have done? You see there is slides_control at your demo have not 0px height but image's height as it should be when page is load.

Comment: Sorry, I realised after posting it was a bit confusing, I actually just copy and pasted your HTML, perhaps you could put it on jsfiddle so I can try and figure out from there? the inline styles are obviously being generated by the plugin when it runs, hence why it is a bit odd.

Comment: You see you have pasted <div class="slides_control" style="position: relative; width: 2820px; left: -940px; height: 0px; "> but in your demo it has not 0px height but 355px as it should be it's calculate the height... But doesn't calculate height at my site, strange...

Comment: Nice one, looks like you fixed it. I got it down to being a css issue after all, was I right?

Comment: Glad you figured it out after all that! Nice one :)

Comment: Slidejs is supposed to be "responsive".  A fixed height and width seems counter productive.